# R shiny app on my OWN website

Tags: r, shiny, hosting

I have a shiny app that has to be hosted on my company's webserver and thus be accessible through our website.
I've googled many variants of this question, but pretty much everything leads to shiny server. 
Is that really necessary? Can't we just put it on our own webservers?

I did found 2 websites of people talking about their own servers, but they both refered to DigitalOcean. We already have an actual webserver, so we don't want to get involved with other providers.

I have no IT background whatsoever, so I hope I'm not asking for something impossible...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you mix two things up. Shiny Server is an **application** to host shiny applications on a server. It is not a physical server service.

You can install Shiny Server on your company's webserver to distribute your shiny apps as long as you installed Linux. This is required for Shiny Server because there are no Microsoft Windows versions available. I set it up on a server with this [manual](http://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/). It is Dean Attali's Blog, maybe you already read it because it also refers to Digital Ocean. But you can use his descriptions on every other server too.

Comment: Oh okay thanks!
Then it's this shiny server application of which there exists an open source version etc? Because currently we were looking at the prices and what we can pay

Comment: Yes, there is an open source version. For more details [see] (https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/)